# restbed on windows: any reasons against using external openssl?

Tags: windows, restbed

while trying to build restbed for our needs and integrate this into jenkins i struggled a bit with openssl builds.

additionally, we already make use of the [Win32OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) library at other related software, so restbed would introduce another openssl variant, which may(will) make it hard to find errors, if any at all.

what are the reasons of using the dependency/openssl version and build/link this one,
instead of using e.g. developers edition of Win32OpenSSL?

Comment: have you tried building restbed using your own openssl library yet?

Comment: i have tried and we are running it with our already used version.